# InputStream Error JavaFX with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, inputstream

I'm using Java FXML in intellij.
I'm trying load FXML,which locate in resources(image below).How repare it?

[image]

Code:

```
public void startMenuStage(Stage MainMenuStage) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, FileNotFoundException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load(MainMenu.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/fxml/Menu.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("Localization.Locate", locale));
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fxmlLoader.getController();
        MainMenuController mainMenuController =  (MainMenuController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        mainMenuController.CloseMenu(MainMenuStage);
        MainMenuScene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720 );
        MainMenuScene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/StyleMenu.css");
        MainMenuStage.setTitle("v.0.1.5.alpha");
        MainMenuStage.setScene(MainMenuScene);
        MainMenuStage.show();
    }
}
```

Error Stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: inputStream is null.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2455)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at Main.MainMenu.startMenuStage(MainMenu.java:27)
    at Controllers.MainLogoController.lambda$Timer$0(MainLogoController.java:45)
```

**UPD1:**
If I change code to that:

```
   String fxmlFile = "/fxml/Menu.fxml";
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = null;
    try {
    root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Errors:

javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified.
unknown path:42

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.resolvePrefixedValue(FXMLLoader.java:421)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:363)
at
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You must make sure that the FXML is included in the classpath. Does IntelliJ consider the resources folder as a source folder?

Comment: I'm create proj with Maven architype. I think it include by default?

Comment: Use the second version for the FXML path, since that is working, and call `loader.setResources(...)` as you do in the first version; obviously, though, you need to call it *before* you call `load()`. BTW it is probably better to do `fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));` and then `root=fxmlLoader.load()`, instead of passing an input stream.

Comment: I add this strings. Another error:    
javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified.
unknown path:42